# Create a Gantt (Stacked Bar Chart) in excel with time breaks

Tags: excel, gantt-chart

I have been struggling with creating an more advanced Gantt chart with Excel than the simple Stacked Bar Chart that is typically used in the examples I have seen in the web.  For my example I would like to group multiple rows for the and entity on one row of the final Gantt.  See the example data below:

```
Employee   Start         End
EMPL1      2:00          4:00
EMPL1      6:00          8:00
EMPL2      1:00          5:00
EMPL3      3:00          4:00
EMPL3      7:00          8:00
```

With the data above I would like the Gantt chart to group items for a single employee into a specific row as shown below.  So for example, Employees 1 & 3 have two separate times, but their data is displayed on a single row in the Gantt.

```
TIME      1    2    3    4    5    6    7   8   9
Empl1          XXXXXXXXXXX         XXXXXXXXXX
Empl2     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Empl3               XXXXXX              XXXXX
```

Can excel generate a report like the one below?  I have done simple Gantts using a start date and a duration to create a Stacked Bar Chart and that works fine, but I haven't been able to find a way to group multiple rows of data together for a single line on a chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but probably easiest with a different data layout and in the example below using Insert Stacked Bar, Switch Row/Column, Y-axis categories in reverse order and X-axis range set to 1-9:

[image: SO24491962 example]

Comment: Excellent answer.  One last question.  What I have done in the past is to create and excel template with the chart and then load data to excel using Java.  Java has very limited support for modifying charts so I typically do as much in the excel template as possible.  What I would like to do would be to setup the template so that all of the duration columns will start off blank and that the range of the columns and rows is dynamically calculated.  I can use Excel VBA scripts if necessary to achieve this.  Could you point me to any examples or walk me through the steps to achieve this?